# Visual Studio adding executable file with same name as dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, assemblies

In Visual Studio 2008, I added WinScp.dll (in project root) as a reference and immediately there was a yellow icon. At compile-time:

- The type or namespace name 'WinSCP' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. Could not load file or assembly 'E:...\winscp.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

After an hour's frustration, I figured out that if I removed WinSCP.exe as a project file (also in project root), everything compiled fine. *Weird!!!!*

The problem is that I need both WinSCP.dll and WinSCP.exe in my output directory. What do I do?

**EDIT**: I understand that there are workarounds, such as renaming the files or changing the paths. I renamed the exe at first; now I rename the dll (thanks @Michael) because it does not require me to also specify the renamed exe in my code.

But why is there a problem in the first place? WinSCP.dll and WinSCP.exe are two different files. Is this a bug in Visual Studio, or an intricacy of dll/exe that I don't understand?

Comment: Presumably WinScp.dll is a .NET assembly, but WinScp.exe is not?

Comment: [WinSCP .NET Assembly](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library)
WinSCP.dll is basically just a wrapper that takes care of process creation for using WinSCP.exe with command line arguments. By default the .dll looks for the executable in the same directory, but that can be changed in the calling code (my current workaround is to change WinSCP.exe to WinSCP_.exe and make the appropriate changes, but there must be a better way).

Comment: Maybe you can store the `WinSCP.exe` file elsewhere and use a post-build step to copy it to the output directory?

Comment: The WinSCP devs suggest renaming the DLL rather than the executable: "You may want to add winscp.exe to your Visual Studio project, to have it copied to Output path automatically (by setting file properties Builder action to None and Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer). Note that it makes winscp.dll and winscp.exe to conflict. You need to rename the winscp.dll to give it a different base name, e.g. winscpnet.dll".  I guess this eliminates the need to modify WinSCP.dll's code? From http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> WinSCP.dll and WinSCP.exe are two different files

Not to the assembly loader, it doesn't pay attention to a filename extension.  All it knows is that it needs to find an assembly with a *display name* of "winscp".  When searching for a match, it first tries an EXE file with that name, next a DLL file.  Something you can see with the Fuslogvw.exe utility.  Display names are described in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/09/14/229254.aspx) by the Microsoft guy that worked on the Fusion component:

> The "name" part is usually the file name of the assembly, **excluding the extension**. So for assembly foo.dll, the "name" part is "foo". Of course, since I said "usually", there are times when the "name" part is not the same as the file name excluding extension. I will discuss this in a bit.

Emphasis added.  So it finds WinSCP.exe first and that's a kaboom, it is not a valid .NET assembly.  The simple workaround is *rename* the DLL, that changes the display name of the assembly.

Comment: Re: "it doesn't pay attention to a filename extension"
I renamed the .exe to nonsensical .com, and it didn't have this problem. It clearly must play attention to the extension at least a little (but apparently only a little).

Comment: I explicitly documented that, "first tries an EXE file with that name, next a DLL file".