# WinSCP .NET Assembly throws "The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to use the WinSCP within my C# project for some ftp automation.
I am using Visual Studio 2012 and am unsure on how to get it to work.

*Things I have done so far:*

- I copied the `WinSCP.exe` into my project folder.
- I imported a reference to the `WinSCPnet.dll` into my project
- I ran `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe Path/To/WINSCPnet.DLL /codebase /tlb`

This is my code as of now:

```
using WinSCP;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
            HostName = "hostname.address.com",
            UserName = "Username",
            Password = "Password"
        };
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);

    }
}
```

When I run this in code I get the following exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'WinSCP, Version=1.0.7.3446, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b5f19f5762436b89' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to
contain an assembly manifest.
```

And Visual Studio's error is: BadImageFormatException was unhandled.

I am not exactly sure how to import WinSCP into my C# program and would appreciate some guidance here.

**Conclusion**
*I was using 5.2.5 Beta and 32bit but my project was 64 bit*

Comment: Read the documentation: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library

Comment: I already did read the documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio adding executable file with same name as dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948643/visual-studio-adding-executable-file-with-same-name-as-dll)

Comment: @HansPassant He has `WinSCPnet.dll` and `WinSCP.exe`, so it does not seem to be the case. (Were he using WinSCP 5.1.x, it would be the case, as it has `WinSCP.dll`).

Comment: Wow, what a coincidence.  Can't do anything without a Fuslogvw trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose your project is 64-bit, while the distributed binary of WinSCP .NET assembly is only 32-bit. Either switch your project to 32-bit or build 64-bit version of the assembly from source code.

Also note that you do not need to register the assembly (`regasm`). That's for COM interop only. While you use it directly.

Comment: My project was 64 bit, once I changed it to 32 bit it worked. Thank you so much for taking the time to help!